# Stylize all control instances in QML application

Tags: styles, controls, qml

I need define some style for different QML controls. Now i have following options:

1. Define style for each control like:

   ```
   TextField {
       text: "Text input"
       style: TextFieldStyle {
       textColor: "white"
       ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Define style in each qml file using it like:

   ```
   Component {
       id: myStyle
       TextFieldStyle {
       textColor: "white"
       ...
       }
   }
   TextField {
       text: "Text input"
       style: myStyle
   }
   ```

Question: how to implement single qml file containing all styles for all used controls which can be reused in every qml file of project?
Which top level element should be in such qml?
As i understand each qml file in project is Component. But if i specify top element as Component, then it will create component in Component, right?

What is best way to implement that?

Comment: You could add a property at the end of your file eg. `property Component {...}`

Answer (score 0):

There are three things to do:

1. Create a single qml file MyStyles.qml containing all colours, text sizes
2. Create simple, re-usable components(e.g. MyLabelText.qml, MyTextInput.qml). Use the style values defined previously.
3. Build your higher level components based in this components (e.g. MyLabeledInputField.qml)